# i want to control CSS of .cylinder::after dynamically in html, how to do this?

Tags: angular, sass, ng-style

i am having sass file with below content

.cylinder::after
content: ''
display: inline-block
width: 75px
height: 11.5px
background: blue
border: 1px solid #000000
border-radius: 50%
position: absolute
left: -1px
bottom: -7.5px
z-index: 0

so here background color is blue but i want it should be red when value is negative so have used below code

=0;then content else other_content">

```
            </div>
```

but I think [ngSyle.cylinder::after] is not correct syntax , so can anyone pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control pseudo elements with Javascript.

What you can do however, is control the parent, and hydrate the child, like so :

```css
.cylinder:after {
  color: red;
}

.cylinder.blue:after {
  color: blue;
}
```